# How to install Swing library for Python based robot framework in Windows?

Tags: java, swing, robotframework, robotframework-swinglibrary

I am new to Robot framework. I use sample GUI application from swinglibrary-1.5.1.jar.

```
java -cp swinglibrary-1.5.1 org.robotframework.swing.testapp.examplesut.TodoListApplication
```

[image]

For that I need to install Swing library in my PC.
Can anybody help me with step by step procedure  to install Swing library (including parameters needs to be set in environmental variables).

Before asking here, I tried this:

```
pip install robotframework-swinglibrary
```

My robot script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    SwingLibrary
Library    DateTime
Resource    ../resources/common/common.robot

*** Keywords ***


*** Test Cases ***

main poc
    [Tags]  poc
    Select Window  Todo List
```

My error trace is:

```
$ robot --include 'poc' data
==============================================================================
Data
==============================================================================
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\workspace\test\data\poc.robot': Importing test library 'SwingLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SwingLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\My Program Files\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\robot.exe
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\python37.zip
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\DLLs
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\lib
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32
  C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
  c:\my program files\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? Perhaps when you used pip, it installed the version for python2 rather than python3.